# last.fm java API get recentTracks of a user within a data range

Tags: java, last.fm

I am trying to get a list of tracks listened to by a user in a specific time range.

According the the last.fm api this is possible with getRecentTracks (see [here](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks)).

But I am using the Java API and the method getRecentTracks does not have input arguments for from and to range:

```
public static de.umass.lastfm.PaginatedResult<de.umass.lastfm.Track> getRecentTracks(java.lang.String user, java.lang.String apiKey) 

public static de.umass.lastfm.PaginatedResult<de.umass.lastfm.Track> getRecentTracks(java.lang.String user, int page, int limit, java.lang.String apiKey)
```

Is this not implemented int java API and how could I extract this?

Thanks,

Comment: User and key are the only required params; everything else is optional. Are you sure the method isn't overridden with the optional params?

Comment: I am not sure, These are the only two functions I find in the class of the lastfm.jar. It's not user, limit, apiKey or page and I don't see any others defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented.

You can write your own implementation handling `from` and `to` UNIX timestamp:

```
public static PaginatedResult<Track> getRecentTracks(String user, int page, 
    int limit, String apiKey, int from, int to) {
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("user", user);
    params.put("limit", String.valueOf(limit));
    params.put("page", String.valueOf(page));
    params.put("from", String.valueOf(from));
    params.put("to", String.valueOf(to));
    Result result = Caller.getInstance().call("user.getRecentTracks", apiKey, params);
    return ResponseBuilder.buildPaginatedResult(result, Track.class);
}
```

Comment: great, I will give it a try!